# How to show whole gitkraken branch tree?

Tags: git, gitkraken

I cloned huge repository from github. I want to examine it in gitkraken, but unfortunately I am able to see only the branch tree from the last half a year. Is it possible to make whole branch tree visible?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the commit tree only shows the last 10.000 or so commits, and it's not possible to increase this number. You can, however, inspect certain files histories up to the point of creation by right click the file and choose `File History`.

EDIT:
Oh, wait, I found the following [here](https://blog.axosoft.com/review-file-history-git/):

> If you’re working with a beastly repo that has more than 2,000 commits, you might need to solo or hide branches to go back further in time.

It seems that only 2.000 commits are shown. If you want to see furhter in the past, you have to hide other commits. A kind of clumsy workaround would be to create a branch at the latest visible commit and just solo that branch: all later commits will be hidden and the earlier 2.000 are shown.

Comment: my commits not showing at all. the commits just 238 commits and i have checklist 'show all commits' and reload still not showing any commits. please help